# How to get Default User Agent to send to server side in the header

Tags: ios

I want to get the default user agent, that is like operating system (ios 10) and etc info.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIDevice` to get system info in iOS.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]; // e.g. @"iOS"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]; // e.g. @"10.0"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]; // e.g. @"iPhone", @"iPod touch"
[[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]; // localized version of model
```